# Pytorch 1.5 optimizer causing inplace operations in .step() (possible bug)

Tags: python, pytorch

In reference to [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/39141). The PyTorch [release notes](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases) mention this change but I'm not sure how to apply their guidelines and there could just be a bug.

This code will display the error.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Hyper Parameters
BATCH_SIZE = 64
LR_G = 0.0001
LR_D = 0.0001 
N_IDEAS = 5  
ART_COMPONENTS = 15 
PAINT_POINTS = np.vstack([np.linspace(-1, 1, ART_COMPONENTS) for _ in range(BATCH_SIZE)])


def artist_works():  # painting from the famous artist (real target)
    r = 0.02 * np.random.randn(1, ART_COMPONENTS)
    paintings = np.sin(PAINT_POINTS * np.pi) + r
    paintings = torch.from_numpy(paintings).float()
    return paintings


G = nn.Sequential(  # Generator
    nn.Linear(N_IDEAS, 128),  # random ideas (could from normal distribution)
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(128, ART_COMPONENTS),  # making a painting from these random ideas
)

D = nn.Sequential(  # Discriminator
    nn.Linear(ART_COMPONENTS, 128),  # receive art work either from the famous artist or a newbie like G
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(128, 1),
    nn.Sigmoid(),  # tell the probability that the art work is made by artist
)

opt_D = torch.optim.Adam(D.parameters(), lr=LR_D)
opt_G = torch.optim.Adam(G.parameters(), lr=LR_G)


for step in range(10000):
    artist_paintings = artist_works()  # real painting from artist
    G_ideas = torch.randn(BATCH_SIZE, N_IDEAS)  # random ideas
    G_paintings = G(G_ideas)  # fake painting from G (random ideas)

    prob_artist0 = D(artist_paintings)  # D try to increase this prob
    prob_artist1 = D(G_paintings)  # D try to reduce this prob

    D_loss = - torch.mean(torch.log(prob_artist0) + torch.log(1. - prob_artist1))
    G_loss = torch.mean(torch.log(1. - prob_artist1))

    opt_D.zero_grad()
    D_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)  # reusing computational graph
    opt_D.step()

    opt_G.zero_grad()
    G_loss.backward()
    opt_G.step()
```

`RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [128, 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 4; expected version 3 instead.`

The only [128,1] tensor parameter would be the linear layer in `D()`. The error comes from somewhere within the `opt_D.step()` call and then calling a `backward()` pass on the retained graph.

The release notes have this example to clone the parameter:

```
def model(input, target, param):
    return (input * param ** 2 - target).norm()

param = torch.randn(2, requires_grad=True)
input = torch.randn(2)
target = torch.randn(2)
sgd = optim.SGD([param], lr=0.001)
loss = model(input, target, param.clone())
loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
sgd.step()
loss.backward()
param.grad
```

Which solves the problem here, but not in the initial example because it's a bit more nuanced as the parameter is coming from the Linear layer of the discriminator model.